# GridView does not exist in current context (updatepanel)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, webforms, updatepanel

I try to put GridView with SqlDataSource and Button inside UpdatePanel but i got some errors. How can i do this?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX6SC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a ContentTemplate. Now it's works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div align="center" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="4" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" Font-Names="Arial" >

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Actions">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="Button3" runat="server" class="btn btn-success btn-md" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","Update.aspx?id={0}") %>' OnClick="Button3_Click1" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="Button4" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","Delete.aspx?id={0}") %>' OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Delete" />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" class="btn btn-info btn-md" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","View.aspx?id={0}") %>' OnClick="Button4_Click" Text="Read" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" Checked="false" Enabled="true"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

This is a way to add a grid view in asp.net and on the back end code you have to write this in C# code

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```